# how to parse a dynamic array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

Haw can i parse this json?

> {"A":{"A":{"1":{"1":"1","2":"2","3":"3","4":"4","5":"5","6":"6","7":"7"},"2":{"1":"8","2":"9","3":"10","4":"11","5":"12","6":"13","7":"14"},"3":{"1":"15","2":"16","3":"17","4":"18","5":"19","6":"20","7":"21"}},"B":{"1":{"1":"22","2":"23","3":"24","4":"25","5":"26","6":"27","7":"28"},"2":{"1":"29","2":"30","3":"31","4":"32","5":"33","6":"34","7":"35"},"3":{"1":"36","2":"37","3":"38","4":"39","5":"40","6":"41","7":"42"}}}}

I try this, but... does not work, and lot of more things but i'm very new on this and i can't resolve myself

```
for (var i = 0; i < datos.A.length; i++) {
    items.push( "<div class='rackCod'>" + val[0] + "</div>" );
}
```

Comment: Object Literals don't have a length property. Use `for(var i in datos.A){}`.

Comment: It's not an array, and it's not JSON, it's a JavaScript object. What do you mean by "parsing" it? It's already an object and does not need parsing. Do you mean trying to find values inside the nested object?

Comment: Thanks por helping me
I'm trying to draw something like this http://www.canalverdepy.com/captura.png

Comment: I found the way
for (var i in datos) {
   items.push( "<div class='rackCod'>" + i);
   for (var j in datos[i]) {
    items.push( "<div class='rackCod'>"  + j);
    for (var k in datos[i][j]) {
     items.push( "<div class='rackposPG'>"  + datos[i][j][k] + "</div>"); 
    }
    items.push( "</div><br><br><br>");
   }
   items.push( "</div>");
   }

Thanks for the answers, it's help me alot